# Navigate back to SilverLight from XNA in hybrid app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna, windows-phone-8

So I'm making a silver light / xna hybrid app.  Everything works fine so far, it starts on a silver light UI, then when a button is pressed there is a very straight forward navigation to the xna portion of the game:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

However when the game is over I want to navigate to a silverlight score screen, but it seems that I no longer have access to the NavigationService within the xna portion of the game.  Is there anyway to navigate to another silverlight page once my game has entered the xna portion of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turns out the main xna page inherits from ApplicationPage just like the silver light pages and does have access to the NavigationService.  Navigating from there works fine.